# symfony2 form how to accept json payload from angular resource

Tags: angularjs, forms, symfony, payload, ngresource

I'm currently trying to combine a Symfony Form with `angularJS`... A Service posts data to a form, that should save an entity to the database. Unfortunately, `ngResource` sends the data as a JSON payload, so that Symfony Forms can't process it... I tried many things on angular side, like changing the headers:

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

I couldn't find much more on angular side, so I thought that I could find a Solution on Symfony Side.
Any Idea how I could get this to work? Angular-Solutions are welcome too of course.

Comment: I would suggest leaving the AngularJS side alone and stick with basic json.  That is more or less standard.  There are a number of articles showing how to use Symfony 2/REST/Forms.  It will take a bit of effort to get everything going but after that it is smooth sailing.  Try: http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/ as a start.  Read the referenced 2012 article if the 2013 article is too terse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, after reading deeper in the documentation. `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bind` doesn't require a Request, it works with an array too. so here's my Solution (the sloppy way, would need some checking of the header, etc. for production use..)

```
public function setFooAction(Request $request){

  $form = $this->createForm();//get the form class, etc...
  $json_data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);//get the response data as array
  $form->bind($json_data); //Bind data to Form

  if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...

  }

}
```

Comment: as of Symfony v2.3 `$form->bind()` is deprecated and will be removed in v3.0 - should use `$form->submit()` instead.

Comment: I get lots of "This form should not contain extra fields" errors doing this :\

Comment: if you simply send an entire angular "entity", you'll probably get a bunch of angular specific variables, which of course are not mapped in your form... check the playload for that, a quick and dirty trick to fix this is to convert it to json and back to an object with angular...