# How do I use an Angular.JS generated form to upload a file (and other fields) through AJAX to Symfony2?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, symfony

I'm trying to send a form generated by Angular.js through an AJAX call to a Symfony controller action in order to be saved. The form is generated in an ng-repeat after receiving some JSON data (including an entry ID). The code looks as follows.

```html
<div ng-repeat="job in sc.careers">
  <div>
    <h2>{[{job.title}]}</h2>
    <span ng-if="job.super">{[{job.super}]}</span>
    <div>
      <h4>Role</h4>
      <span ng-bind-html="job.role"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Required Skills</h4>
      <span ng-bind-html="job.skills"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Media</h4>
      Some other content \ media
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="join-us">
    <button ng-click="sc.joinUs[$index] = true" ng-hide="sc.joinUs[$index]">Apply for this position</button>
    <div ng-show="sc.joinUs[$index]">
      <h4>Join Us</h4>
      <span>Some random text</span>

      <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="{[{job.id}]}" />
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
        <label for="motivation">Cover Letter & CV link</label>
        <textarea id="motivation" name="motivation"></textarea>

        <label for="resume">Upload your resume</label>
        <input type="file" name="resume">
        <button type="submit">Send your application</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

* most class names have been redacted to keep the code as relevant to the question as possible

I have not yet placed an ng-click -> submit directive. Also, my Angular is configured for the use of the "{[{" and "}]}" delimiters so as not to interfere with TWIG.

I have searched the internet for possible answers but they all pertain to Symfony generated forms (which include validation tokens). Other answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768073/symfony2-form-how-to-accept-json-payload-from-angular-resource)) don't quite describe the Angular side of things or don't describe sending the entire form.

In the end, I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. If it's too complicated I'd even settle for not using AJAX at all and submitting directly to Symfony. (actually, the only reason I want to use AJAX is to make the site feel more "snappy").

For what it's worth I'm using the latest stable versions of PHP, Symfony and Angular.JS at the time of writing.

## Update

So i managed to send the data back to the controller by using an Agular JS module that enables the use of ng-model on file inputs and by using FormData like so:

```
var formObject = new FormData;

        formObject.append('email',      self.careers[index].application.email);
        formObject.append('motivation', self.careers[index].application.motivation);
        formObject.append('resume',     self.careers[index].application.file);
        formObject.append('jobID',      self.careers[index].id);

        $http.post('/app_dev.php/jobs/apply', formObject, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } // Allows angular to choose the proper Content-Type
        })
```

The only problem left now is that Symfony does not recognize my form data as being valid. The controller action looks like this (for now).

```
public function applyAction(Request $request) {
    $jobApplication = new JobApplications(); // This is the entity I use to store everything.

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($jobApplication)
        ->add('jobId')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('coverLetter')
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $response = array (
        'isValid' => $form->isValid(),             // false
        'isSubmitted' => $form->isSubmitted(),     // false < that's why the form is invalid
        'isErrors' => $form->getErrorsAsString()   // empty array
    );



    if ($form->isValid()) { // is not valid so the following section is not complete
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $jobApplication->upload();

        $em->persist($jobApplication);
        $em->flush();

        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('idea_presentation_careers'));
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? With files uploading or symfony form handling?

Comment: One problem is that even as of 1.4, angularjs does not support the type=file for the input element.  So you need to start by downloading one of the file directives and work from there.  I don't have a solution that I'm happy with so I'll just leave at that.

Comment: I'm already on to a solution but it isn't secure nor does it work on IE 9 or lower. I'll update my answer as soon. @VadimAshikhman The problem I was having was that I didn't know a way to go about it that was both secure and backwards compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to upload a multipart file using angular js spring mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810352/how-to-upload-a-multipart-file-using-angular-js-spring-mvc)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a duplicate, I would have loved for it to be in order to have a straight answer - I'm using PHP, that is Java, and an entirely different framework. At any rate, I think the problem was the fact that I was sending JSON encoded data to Symfony and Symfony doesn't know what to do with it.